# UITableView data reload issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Kinda stuck on this question, not sure how to reload the data into the table. Any help would be much appreciated.... I've included the code below.

Q: Inside this new empty block, reload the data for the table view. The table view property is named 'tableView'.

```
#import "LeaderboardViewController.h"

@implementation LeaderboardViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_queue_t queue= dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) ;
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
          self.blogPosts= [BlogLoader getRecentPosts];
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
          });

    })

}

@end
```

Comment: What about `[self.tableView reloadData];` ?

Comment: Put a suitable title which will describe the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

The `UITableView` class has a `reloadData` method for exactly this purpose.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad { 
      [super viewDidLoad];
      dispatch_queue_t queue= dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) ; dispatch_async(queue, ^{
          self.blogPosts= [BlogLoader getRecentPosts];
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
               [self.tableView reloadData]; // reloadData will load your table with contents
          });
      })
 }
```